# Angular 9: Can't get a blob response with HttpClient POST request

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a zip file as blob from a http POST request, but the post method overload can't be resolved

```
const options = {
  responseType: 'blob' as const
};
Observable<Blob> blob = this.http.post<Blob>(path, data, options)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

It seems that this always resolves to the other post method overload that returns `Observable<ArrayBuffer>`

Can someone please help me out with this? My Angular version is `~9.1.1` I always get `error TS2769: No overload matches this call.`

Answer (score 3):

I've found the hack to make this work. Cheers!

```
responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
```

Comment: That looks odd.  `responseType: 'blob'` should work

Answer (score -1):

I have done for xls, you can try similar for zip file too

```
  downloadFile(inputs: className) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
     .set('Accept', 'application/xlsx; charset=utf-8');
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}url/downloadxls`;

    return this.http.post(url, inputs, { headers, observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```